# How to set the nginx's IP address when sending datagram?

Tags: nginx

The machine has 2 ip address, first is 192.168.0.10, and the other one is 192.168.0.12, 192.168.0.12 is a VIP(keepalived).

I wanna nginx send data out to targe machine with the source IP VIP 192.168.0.12, but, target  machine detect the ip is 192.168.0.10.

Is there any way to set the nginx source ip to the VIP 192.168.0.12?